# Платформер на Unity

Tags: unity3d

Хочу попробовать написать небольшую 2D игру в жанре платформер, где будет игрок, который ходит и собирает какие-то монетки и уворачивается от врагов. Собственно хотелось бы узнать как лучше рисовать саму карту (дорогу). Т.е. найти готовые (или самому нарисовать) дороги и их расставить или программно как-то размножать дорогу? Как лучше это реализовать с точки зрения производительности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым делом, изучи документацию и уроки Unity по [TileMap](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/intro-2d-world-building-w-tilemap). Причём, насколько я знаю, такой системой можно делать как платформер "сбоку" (e.g. Mario), так и сверху под углом (e.g. Undertale).

> Собственно хотелось бы узнать как лучше рисовать саму карту (дорогу). Т.е. найти готовые (или самому нарисовать) дороги и их расставить или программно как-то размножать дорогу?

Над визуальной частью лучше работать, когда игра более-менее функционирует. Пока лучше скачать в "Google Картинках" готовые [тайл-сеты](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&biw=1604&bih=770&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=s3tiW5X0D8aP6AS15ZPQBA&q=tileset%2032x32%20&oq=tileset%2032x32%20&gs_l=img.3..0i30k1j0i5i30k1l5j0i8i30k1l2j0i24k1.19890.21541.0.23324.2.2.0.0.0.0.95.189.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.2.189...0i19k1j0i7i30i19k1j0i8i30i19k1.0.trixybQYla8).

Насчёт размещения дорог программно или вручную: все делают по-разному. Уникальные локации, как я считаю, лучше самому обустроить, в то время как какие-то повторяющиеся коридоры удобней задавать программно.

Более, чем уверен, что всё это облегчит тебе разработку.

Comment: Спасибо за советы!

Comment: Не за что! (･ω<)☆